# Display XML in HTML

Tags: javascript, xml, html

I need to display an XML file in a HTML file. The cookie tells it which folder its in.

```
    var username = getCookie("username"),
    docUrl = "http://officedocs.freeserver.me/userdata/" + username + "/docs.xml",
    xmlhttp, xmlDoc, finalStr, x, i;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.open("GET", docUrl, false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML; 

finalStr = "<div class='well'><table>";
x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("document");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
    finalStr += "<tr><td>";
    finalStr += "<img src='toolbar_documents.png'/>";
    finalStr += "</td><td>";
    finalStr += "<a href='" + x[i].getElementsByTagName("url")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "'>";
    finalStr += x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    finalStr += "</a></td></tr>";
}
finalStr += "</table>";
document.write(finalStr);
```

Heres the XML:

```
<document>
<name>New Document</name>
<url>http://example.com</url>
</document>
```

It won't write the XML file, it could be the `document` variable,

*Why* won't it write it?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't expect much to work after you overwrite **document**

Comment: Also, you can't make cross-domain AJAX calls - you'll have to do something special for that. You have a few syntax errors too - like in the line `document.write("<a href='"x[i].getE` - you need to concatenate the strings. Here's a cleaned up version of your code, not functioning or anything: http://jsfiddle.net/VEuhA/

Comment: thanks @Ian i'll update it